# Why is my setState not working when passed as an argument to a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, setstate

For the function **fetchApiAndSetStateForWrongGuesses()** I pass it two parameters called **randNum** and **wrongGuess**. randNum is just a number but **wrongGuess** is supposed to be a state. The problem is that when I pass **wrongGuess** to the function **fetchApiAndSetStateForWrongGuesses()** the setState doesn't works. By the time it hits the console.log it just prints out an empty string because thats what the constructor initialized it to be. How can I get it so that setState actually works depending on what state I pass to it?

```
class PokemonGenerator extends Component {
totalPokemon = 151

constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        currentImg: "https://d.newsweek.com/en/full/822411/pikachu-640x360-pokemon-anime.jpg?w=1600&h=1200&q=88&f=3ed1c0d6e3890cbc58be90f05908a8f5",
        currentName: "",
        wrongChoice1: "",
        wrongChoice2: "",
        wrongChoice3: "",
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}

handleClick(event) {
    // event.preventDefault()
    const randNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)
    const randNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)
    const randNum3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)
    const randNum4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalPokemon)
    

    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum1)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({ 
            currentImg: response['sprites']['front_default'],
            currentName: response.name
        }, function() {console.log(`CORRECT ANSWER: ${this.state.currentName}`)})
    })

    this.fetchApiAndSetStateForWrongGuesses(randNum2, this.state.wrongChoice1)
    this.fetchApiAndSetStateForWrongGuesses(randNum3, this.state.wrongChoice2)
    this.fetchApiAndSetStateForWrongGuesses(randNum4, this.state.wrongChoice3)
}

fetchApiAndSetStateForWrongGuesses(randNum, wrongGuess) {

    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                wrongGuess: response.name
            }, function () {console.log(`Wrong Choice: ${wrongGuess}`)})
        })
}
```

Comment: `wrongGuess` is not the name of a state value, it's the name of the second parameter passed into the `fetchApiAndSetStateForWrongGuesses(randNum, wrongGuess) { ... }` function. I think you meant to do `function () {console.log(`Wrong Choice: ${this.state.wrongGuess}`)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your callback function, `wrongGuess` is still bound to the argument that you passed to the function. `setState` updates `this.state`, so you need to access the new value from there.

```
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                wrongGuess: response.name
            }, function () {console.log(`Wrong Choice: ${this.state.wrongGuess}`)})
        })
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Your explanation makes sense. So paraphrasing in my own word: basically the wrongGuess in the callback function is pointed to the wrongGuess in the argument (which itself was pointed to an empty string as initialized in the constructor). So even though setState updated, the wrongGuess in the callback function was still "pointed" to the empty string it was initially. In other words, the setState WAS updating it's just that console.log was looking at the wrong thing. I hope I got that right.

Comment: Yep, you got it. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the context in which `this` exists.
Try doing this:

```
fetchApiAndSetStateForWrongGuesses(randNum, wrongGuess) {
    const self = this
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + randNum)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            self.setState({
                wrongGuess: response.name
            }, function () {console.log(`Wrong Choice: ${wrongGuess}`)})
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have `wrongGuess` state in your initial states

```
 this.state = {
            currentImg: "https://d.newsweek.com/en/full/822411/pikachu-640x360-pokemon-anime.jpg?w=1600&h=1200&q=88&f=3ed1c0d6e3890cbc58be90f05908a8f5",
            currentName: "",
            wrongChoice1: "",
            wrongChoice2: "",
            wrongChoice3: "",
        }
```